# JavasSript (no jQuery) find multiple classes and add new class to each

Tags: javascript, loops

I can find examples using jQuery, but I can't find answers how to do this in pure JavaScript.

Is it possible to combine these two class loops using JavaScript to simplify the code. I am going to end up with approx 20 classes for a project I am working on.

```
var srtClass1 = document.getElementsByClassName('class1');
for(var i = 0; i < srtClass1.length; i++) {
    srtClass1[i].classList.add('newClass');
    srtClass1[i].classList.remove('class1');
}
var srtClass2 = document.getElementsByClassName('class2');
for(var i = 0; i < srtClass2.length; i++) {
    srtClass2[i].classList.add('newClass');
    srtClass2[i].classList.remove('class2');
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve concretly ? Add X classes to X elements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this. You just have to fill the array with all of the classes you want to remove.

```js
var classes = ['.class1', '.class2', '.class3'];
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(classes.join(','));

for (let element of elements) {
  element.classList.add('newClass');
    
  for (let className in classes) {
    element.classList.remove(className);    
  }
}
```

```css
.box { 
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.class1 { background: red; }
.class2 { background: green; }
.class3 { background: blue; }

.newClass { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<div class="box class1"></div>
<div class="box class2"></div>
<div class="box class3"></div>
```

Comment: @Devlin this works except for the second part the original class is not removed. Thankyou for this. If you could help with the removing the classx that would be great. In the meantime I will try and work that part out.

Comment: I worked it out. I love it when people like those who added solutions on this question, thank you all. const classes = ['.class1', '.class2', '.class3'];
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(classes.join(','));

const classNames = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3'];

console.log(elements);
console.log(classNames);

for (let element of elements) {
  element.classList.add('newClass');
    
  for (let className of classNames) {
    element.classList.remove(className);  
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the 2 collections:

```
var srtClass1 = [...document.getElementsByClassName('class1'), ...document.getElementsByClassName('class2')];
for(var i = 0; i < srtClass1.length; i++) {
    srtClass1[i].classList.add('newClass');
    srtClass1[i].classList.remove('class1');
    srtClass1[i].classList.remove('class2');
}
```

And you can use higher order functions:

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('class1'), ...document.getElementsByClassName('class2')].forEach( el => {
    el.classList.add('newClass');
    el.classList.remove('class1');
    el.classList.remove('class2');
});
```

And even better (since `classList.remove` supports multiple arguments):

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName('class1'), ...document.getElementsByClassName('class2')].forEach( el => {
    el.classList.add('newClass');
    el.classList.remove('class1', 'class2');
});
```

Or if you want you can use `querySelectorAll`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.class1, .class2').forEach(el => {
    el.classList.add('newClass');
    el.classList.remove('class1', 'class2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try making a list of the classes, then iterating over that instead:

```js
function changeClasses() {
  let classNames = ['class1', 'class2'];

  classNames.forEach(className => {
    const node = document.querySelector(`.${className}`);
    
    if (node != null) {
      node.classList.add('newClass');
      node.classList.remove(className);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.class1 {
  color: green;
}

.class2 {
  color: blue;
}

.newClass {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="class1">class1</div>
  <div class="class2">class2</div>
  
  <button onclick="changeClasses()">Change classes</button>
</body>
```